Flutter: Accessing external sd card media files for audio player (Direct path vs Scoped storage)
I am writing a music player app in Flutter, aimed primarily at playing audio files in android external sd storage folders like "storage/emulated/0/music". As per my study, from API 30 onwards, scoped storage must be used. The file_picker plugin for flutter provides the cached storage path, which is then saved to a sqlite database. The same path is then retrieved afterwards as Uri for playback.
My questions are as follows:
a) If all the files were in device external sd storage already, and now they have to be stored in scoped storage as well, won't it take twice as much space?
b) When the user clears the app cache in the App information settings, these scoped storage files are deleted, rendering the paths saved in the database useless. The user will again have to create new playlists from scratch because the new scoped storage files will have different paths. What possible approaches can be taken to ensure consistency and persistence of both files and database.
I have tried the file_picker and filesystem_picker plugins for flutter.
file_picker plugin generates a scoped storage path and file. Multiple files can be picked at the same time. The original files also remain on the original external SD card location. Double the space until the cache is cleared. Also, the database is rendered useless after clearing cache.
filesystem_picker gives the original path of the file and does not generate scoped storage. Only one file can be picked at a time. Database remain consistent and persistent.
But is it a violation of Google’s api policy? I checked that apps like jetaudio and poweramp have original paths to the files mentioned in their playlists.

external sd-card storage ? You mean external  storage when you refer to /storage/emulated/0/Music. With sd-storage you suggest files from a removable micro-sd. Confusing.

And who put those audio files there? You app? Or how?

filesystem_picker gives the original path of the file But is that path readable?

file_picker plugin generates a scoped storage path and file You mean that the plugin makes a copy of the file and then you get the path to the copied file? This is very awkward.

apps like jetaudio and poweramp have original paths to the files mentioned in their playlists. With which Android versions on used devices? Maybe they went for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Yes, I mean sd-storage. The direct path given by filesystem_picker is readable as we obtain READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permissions first. file_picker makes a copy of the file and then we get the path to the copied file. Don't know what jetaudio and poweramp went with.

audio files downloaded independently from any website, pc or any other device.

You can just list the Music directory. Then you know all files.

You can also query the MediaStore for all audio files.
